# mysql query to Identify which sql table column contains given string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, dbms-output

Given:

```
TABLE : columns(column1(primary key),column2,column3)

column1        column2       column3
1920           abc           def
1930           xyz           hji
1940           def           abc
```

Now, how to find column_name among column2 or column3 if we are given with a string in those columns?

For eg:we will be always given column 1 value i.e 1920; Some string from column 2 or column3 will be given too for eg: abc. So, we need to identify in 1920 "abc" was in column1 or column2 via mysql query.

Comment: what if both the columns contain the same string?

Comment: no both the columns will not contain same string i.e in 1920; column2 and column3 will contain different values

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: You should consider doing this in your application code (by maintaining a dictionary kind data structure Or even in XML) rather in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column2 = 'abc' THEN 'column2'
            WHEN column3 = 'abc' THEN 'column3'
       END AS which_column
FROM yourTable
WHERE column1 = 1920
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67e35/1)

Comment: its not giving any output

Comment: @NikitaGupta I added a sqlfiddle demo that shows it works.